# Are ASIO completion handlers invoked through the strand for cancelled operations?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Say there's a pending asynchronous operation with its completion handler wrapped by a strand when it is cancelled - for instance by closing a socket, cancelling a timer etc.

So, as I see it, the completion handlers will be enqueued with the error code `operation_aborted`. Now they can be dequeued by the `io_service` to be dispatched.

Is the way I'm telling this story right? If so, when the `io_service` invokes the completion handler, does it do through the strand even if they result from cancelled operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. It is an invariant that every asynchronous operation that is started completes. Regardless of the error code or success, the completion handler is executed the same way -- if it's strand wrapped, the handler will execute on the strand.

Typically you don't need to do anything in this case and the handler just checks for `operation_aborted` and `return`s. But if you want to do anything, you can. Also, the destruction of the callback object may cause things to happen. For example, if the invocation of the completion handler was through a `shared_ptr`, the destruction of that `shared_ptr` may trigger other destructors to run.